# How to change Fancybox preloader image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I want replace default Fancybox1.3.4 image preloader (fancy_loading.png) with another preloader.

The Fancybox preloader coded not only in css, but also in javascript itself.
Seems, there are two places in javascript, at least:

```
        _animate_loading = function() {
        if (!loading.is(':visible')){
            clearInterval(loadingTimer);
            return;
        }

        $('div', loading).css('top', (loadingFrame * -40) + 'px');

        loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;
    };
```

and

```
    $.fancybox.showActivity = function() {
    clearInterval(loadingTimer);

    loading.show();
    loadingTimer = setInterval(_animate_loading, 66);
};

$.fancybox.hideActivity = function() {
    loading.hide();
};
```

So customizing the preloader will require modifying javascript too. 
How can I change fancybox-1.3.4 javascript to set custom preloader image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS declaration is here:

```
#fancybox-loading div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 480px;
  background-image: url('fancybox.png');
}
```

They are using a sprite for the background image and changing the background-position to animate it. If you're going to use a `loading.gif` image, then you won't need to animate it.

You need to change the `background-image` path, `height`, and `width` to cater to your new image. You may want to comment out their JS code for the animation so that it doesn't conflict.

The `loading div` is being declared here:

```
$('body').append(
  tmp = $('<div id="fancybox-tmp"></div>'),
  loading = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>'),
  overlay = $('<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>'),
  wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-wrap"></div>')
);
```

You can either piggyback on the `loading` variable or simply change the styling on `#fancybox-loading`. You'll then need to remove any reference to `loadingTimer` and `loadingFrame`. Comment out this entire function:

```
/*_animate_loading = function() {
  if (!loading.is(':visible')){
  clearInterval(loadingTimer);
    return;
  }

  $('div', loading).css('top', (loadingFrame * -40) + 'px');

    loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;
};*/
```

Modify the following function:

```
$.fancybox.showActivity = function() {
  //clearInterval(loadingTimer);

  loading.show();
  //loadingTimer = setInterval(_animate_loading, 66);
};
```

That should do it. You don't want `loading` to have any `setInterval` on it since you won't be animating it, but you do want it to hide/show conditionally.

Comment: Yes, I wanted set new preloader using animated loader.gif. Is the aboved javascripts the only places that must be uncommented in fancybox JS? There is also CSS written before declaration you specified: `#fancybox-loading {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: -20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1104;
 display: none;
}`  Should be `width` & `height` adjusted accordingly too? Also, `margin-top` & `margin-left`: what are these settings used for?

Comment: Not work for me. Seems requires more modification of JS file.

Comment: It appears as though I was too quick to pull the trigger. Yes, there is a container `div` that needs to be modified, as well. I'm going to look at the JS in a few to see what else needs to be commented out/edited.

Comment: I modified my answer. Please have a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I did these mods, it works, but have some problems:
it show preloader straight after opening page, and stay with it. When click on preloader  it hides itself, but lock thumbnails, so when click on thumbnail, window not appear. When refresh page, preloader shown again. Modal window shown when click directly on thumb, without closing preloader. Also, is there special need for container div in CSS: `#fancybox-loading div` or first `#fancybox-loading` is enough just to add image path?

Comment: I hope this trouble is worth saving some bucks for upgrading :)

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the edited script and how you're using it. `#fancy-loading` is hidden by default, therefore it must be showing via JS on page load. The edits that I have asked you to make should not have affected that.

Comment: I find a `semicolon` is required before function (line 787), so in line 770 (right above the uncommented part)  I replaced comma `,` with semicolon `;` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options -

1) Upgrade to v2 as it is now using animated gif

2) Ŗeplace `showActivity` and `hideActivity` methods with yours, e.g., after including js file -

```
$.fancybox.showActivity = function() {
    /* Add your animated gif to page ... */
}
```

Comment: I preffer second option, adjusting v1.3.4 Would this be correct mods: `$.fancybox.showActivity = function() {
  F.hideActivity();

$('<div id="fancybox-loading"></div>').click(F.cancel).appendTo('body');
},

$.fancybox.hideActivity = function() {
    $("#fancybox-loading").remove();
},`

Comment: yes, something like that. Replace "F.hideActivity();" with "$.fancybox.hideActivity" and "F.cancel" with something appropriate

Comment: One note: should I also remove `<div></div>` from inside a `loading = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>'),` that is `loading = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"></div>'),`? (if use css container div as in fancybox v2)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to change so much just in js file comment some lines:

```
$.fancybox.showActivity = function() {
    //clearInterval(loadingTimer);

    loading.show();
    //loadingTimer = setInterval(_animate_loading, 66);
};
```

Thats all and it will work, but remember change in correct file because where are jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js and jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js