# How to add text to Fancy Box Loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, spinner

When clicking on a link I need to load a huge pdf on FancyBox overlay. Until the pdf is loaded I'm displaying a FancyBox loader. The problem is I need to add a text like "Please Wait...etc" in the FancyBox loader. Can any one help?

This is My Code:

```
    <p>
        <a class="fancypdf" href="hugepdf.pdf">Click
            Here To View The PDF</a>
    </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancypdf").click(function(event) {
            $.fancybox.open(this.href, {
                type : "iframe"
            });
            $.fancybox.showLoading();
            $("iframe.fancybox-iframe").load(function() {
                $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                content: {
                    text: 'Loading...',}
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

### P.S.

You can modify following fiddle.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/PudLq/586/)

Comment: You can edit fancy css styles `#fancybox-loading div {` and append your custom html contents to loding overlay. I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367943/how-to-change-fancybox-preloader-image) can help you more

Comment: But I need to customize the Fancybox loader only on click of a paticular link in my project. Other places the default one should only be laoded.

Answer (score 7):

Please have a look at below modifications:

Updated Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/PudLq/619/

1) added CSS class as:

```
#fancybox-loading{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -108px;
    text-align: center;
}
#fancybox-loading div{
    margin: auto;
}
.overrideLoading{
    background: none !important;
    color: white;
    width: 92px !important;
}
```

2) after showing loading animation; altering the loading div HTML as per our need as follows:

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
$('#fancybox-loading').append("<div class='overrideLoading'>Please Wait...</div>");
```

3) On hiding the animation; As suggested by "rockmandew" there is absolutely no need of reverting our HTML/CSS changes. On calling `$.fancybox.showLoading()` again directly; default loading animation will be shown to user. I have tested it and added one more link in fiddle to show default loading animation. Please click on "Show Default loading" to see that effect.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Nearly but spinner should be shown too. Text should be place under the spinner

Comment: Is there way make label out of fancy animation square and make text longer th ananimation box

Comment: Do you want "Please wait..." text without black background?

Comment: @gstackoverflow- was that helpful. Does that solved your problem?

Comment: Actually yes but I cannot vote already(  I waited grace period

Comment: Glad to know it helped you @gstackoverflow ...`:)`

Answer (score 0):

Following vijayP's answers:

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/kmfeppec/

I modified his CSS class of "overrideLoading":

```
.overrideLoading{
    background: none !important;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
}
```

As you can see I added a "position:absolute" and a "top" position - you can modify this to however you need it to appear.

Next I altered his jQuery, which I modified to actually append a new element:

```
$('#fancybox-loading div').append("<div class='overrideLoading'>Please Wait...</div>");
```

As you can see, that reduced your required jQuery to one line.

Finally, I removed the last part of the function, which was removing the class. Since this is no longer required, you can just keep the FancyBox "hideLoading" call.

For learning purposes, I removed the following from the last function:

```
$('#fancybox-loading div').removeClass("overrideLoading");
$('#fancybox-loading div').text("");
```

Again, here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/kmfeppec/

---

**First Update:**

I saw that the first user to answer, updated his answer and while works, I would suggest shying away from "!important" tags as much as possible. I too refined my answer and developed a solution that didn't use any !important tags.

1. What was originally: *$('#fancybox-loading div').append("Please Wait...");* was now changed to:

   ```
   $('#target ~ #overlay').append("<div class='overrideLoading'>Please Wait...</div>");
   ```

I noticed an earlier comment from you, which specified that you wanted to target specific loading overlays - what this function does is it: Selects every '#overlay' element that is preceded by a '#target' element - you can insert whatever target you want.

2. I removed all instances of the "!important" tag - this is just best/standard practice.

   ```
   .overrideLoading{
       color: white;
       position: absolute;
       top: 86px;
       left: 16px;
   }
   ```

Updated JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/kmfeppec/7/

Comment: is there way make text wider than animation?

Comment: Also, if you want the text outside of the overlay box, all you need to do is adjust the "top" position. If the background stays white, you will also have to obviously change the color of the text. (I noticed, what I think was you asking for this on your comments above.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a chance to tweak the resulting positioning being a little off-center, but this may be a more simple solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/PudLq/621/

Simply add your text to an `:after` pseudo element with a `content:` rule and modify the styles of the loading wrapper to accomodate.

here's the CSS I added:

```
#fancybox-loading {
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;}

#fancybox-loading:after {
    content:"Please wait...";
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;}

#fancybox-loading div {margin:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a forked version of your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwx41sbp/).

I've basically `span` with the text "Please Wait". Then I've applied some CSS to that to position it as you did with `#fancybox-loading` .

Here is the new javascript code -

```
$(".on").click(function () {
    var target = $('#target');
    var overlay = $('#overlay');
    overlay.width(target.width()).height(target.height()).css({
        'left': target.position().left,
        'top': target.position().top
    }).fadeIn(200);
    $.fancybox.showLoading();
    $('#fancybox-loading').css({
        'left': (target.width() - $('#fancybox-loading').width()) / 2,
        'top': (target.height() - $('#fancybox-loading').height()) / 2,
        'margin': 0
    });
    var labelWidth = 80;
    $('body').append($('<span>', {
        'class': 'waitText'
    }).text("Please Wait").css({
        'width': labelWidth,
        'left': (target.width() - labelWidth) / 2,
        'top': ((target.height() - $('#fancybox-loading').height()) / 2) + $('#fancybox-loading').height()
    }));
});
$(".off").click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(200);
    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
    $('.waitText').remove();
});
```

And my new CSS -

```
.waitText {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```